# SQLite - Display in the terminal content of a list of tables time it

Tags: sqlite

I achieved to display a list of table names of interest I have in my database with the following function:

```
SELECT name
FROM sqlite_master
WHERE type = 'table'
AND name LIKE '%#_1' ESCAPE '#';
```

(It is not the subject but it return me a list of table names finishing by "_1")
Now what I would like to do is to display the content of all these tables in one command (just like if I was using cat *) and I would like to time this command.

So what should be the command ?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do all tables have the same number of columns?

Comment: Unfortunately No, but most of them yes. What is your idea ?

Comment: A single SQL query generates an output that looks like a table, i.e., it has a fixed number of columns. What is the exact output that you want to get?

Comment: @CL. I simply want the equivalent command of  "cat *_1" in SQL, obivously for tables not for files in a folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with a single SQL command.
You have to generate a series of SELECT statements, one for each table, and execute all of them.

Comment: So I have to write for example a script containing each SELECT * from <tablename>, one line per table ?
It sounds really strange that there is not a simpler solution.
What if I use JOIN ? it could work in one command (even if it would be a really big one) ?

Comment: No, a join combines related rows, and there is no relation.